# Java kernel Jupyter-Notebook didn't fail on illegal Java Generic Code

Tags: java, jupyter-notebook

I download Java 9 kernel jupyter notebook kernel from [github](https://github.com/scijava/scijava-jupyter-kernel)
I write some piece of illegal code for Java Generics.In Netbeans this code fails with java.lang.RuntimeException.But it didn't fail on Jupyter-Notebook.

```
List<? super Integer> list=new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(new Object());
```

Out 17:true

Possible Reason: Jupyter notebook is a lexical scanner.Maybe It doesn't work on Java Virtual Machine.

I am beginner for Jupyter notebook .Is Jupyter notebook a lexical scanner or IDE which has a compiler and JVM?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question, but a bug report, which you should (probably) put in an issue on the github.

Comment: Thanks.I am new for Jupyter Notebook.I think that it behaves like a lexical scanner(like an online java compiler).Maybe It just compiled the code  and It did not run on JVM(Java Virtual Machine)

Comment: This code doesn't compile either though, so I guess _something_ is wrong. I've used jupyter notebook a few times with python, and there it _does_ actually run the code.